# Gradle 3.3 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently using Java 6

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android studio showing me this error
error:Gradle 3.3 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently using Java 6.

while I am using Java 8 in my SDK
[image]

Comment: shouldn't you set `sourceCompatibility = 1.7` and `targetCompatibility = 1.7`?

Comment: Does your `JAVA_HOME` [environment property](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) point to JDK 1.7?

Comment: JAVA_HOME point to "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
"

Comment: It is a project working with a friend and I should not edit in it so I can't set sourceCompatibility and target